# How to ignore printing "None Object" in python

Tags: python-3.x, function

```
n = int(input())

def reverse(num):
    while num > 0:
        return f"{num}{reverse(num - 1)}"

result = reverse(n)
print(result)
```

I have some code lines as above. (Incase Input n = 5)It prints "54321None" instead of "54321" as I expected.
Please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What happens if it recursively goes into ```reverse()``` and ```num == 0```?   What does it return?

Comment: Advice -  don't use Python built-in function *reverse* as the function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last iteration will always be a 0. If you just call reverse(0) it will return None, so that is the problem.
Without rewriting too much code the 'simple' solution could be:

```
return f"{num}{reverse(num-1)if num-1 != 0 else ''}"
```

This only executes the reverse function if the variable you pass into reverse is not 0. Otherwise it will return Nothing.

Comment: It's good &  detail explanation.   The statement can be simplified a little like this - ```return f"{num}{reverse(num-1)if num-1 else ''}"```   And it's worthwhile to mention to avoid re-use *buil-in* *reverse* as the redefined function name...